# jQuery wrap equivalent in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Is there any equivalent of jQuery wrap in ReactJS ?

I am trying to wrap `menuContents` with below element

```
<ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"></ul>
```

`menuContents` is populated like this

```
let menuContents = this.state.menu.map((menu)=> 
        <li>
          {menu}
        </li>
```

I am looking for a function (if any) like

```
menuContents.wrap(<ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"></ul>);
```

so that the return is

```
<ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li>
     One
   </li>
   <li>
     Two
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Esko, I agree, I will change that to `<li>`

Comment: @Jayavel I am doing like that now, wondering if there is something inbuilt so instead of line 20-21 I can use `menuContents.wrap(<ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"></ul>);`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such a thing in React, but you can write your own easily using [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```
function myWrap(element, wrapper) {
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, element);
    wrapper.appendChild(element);
}
```

and to use it

```
let wrapper= document.createElement('div');
myWrap(myElement, wrapper);
```

Comment: avoid direct DOM manipulations - react can overwrite theese changes during rerendering updated components

Answer (score 1):

**React is not a set of string-glue helpers**, it operates on components and of course can manage this use case by simple component or HOC pattern making more composable.

You can create simple component (not even HOC neither using render props) to wrap/decorate items (children) with 'parent' (`<ul />`) structure and styling used like this:

```
<UlComponent ulClasses="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
  {menuContents}
</UlComponent>
```

Items will be in `this.props.children` and classes in `this.props.ulClasses`. It's simplest react usage. (Items should be `key`'ed). UlComponent can be trivial.

```
const UlComponent = (props) => <ul className={props.ulClasses}>{props.children}</ul>
```

Using HOCs you can create more complex components (inject props, global state, i18n) using composing. You can have a few levels of components depth (virtual DOM tree is cheap) rendering to single (or none) real DOM element hiding all its complecity/data/dependencies. **No more (error prone) manual search/manipulate DOM nodes/properties/handlers.**